# about sending messages among bg.html, popup.html and contentscript.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

In my extension, when a button named `mybuttonl` in `popup.html` is 
clicked, it sends a message `"getvar"` to `contentscript.js`, which in turn sends a message `"I want var1"` to `background.html` to get an object named `var1`. (A button named `mybutton2` is set up likewise, except it gets the `var2` object when clicked).

How should I implement this?

What's more, I am a little confused about the `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` and `chrome.extension.sendRequest` methods. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

onRequest.addListener and sendRequest is part of Chrome's extension Messaging. Which is located here http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Basically, you listen for a request using "onRequest.addListener" that someone sent from triggering a "sendRequest".

In your case, you put a "[onRequest.addListener](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest)" in your content script to listen for requests coming from the Popup (using [sendRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest)). And from your content script, you can return a response back to your popup to handle what is happening. In your popup, you have direct access to the background page using [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage).

If you want your content script to communicate to your background page as well (which is not needed since your making stuff more complicated), you can add a "onRequest.addListener" to your background page which only listens for requests coming from the content script. To do that, [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) explains it perfectly. "sender.tab" if true, is a content script.

The example below (untested) shows what I mean about message passing. Remember, try to keep stuff simple, not complex.

## Example

### Popup.html

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "fromPopup", tabid: tab.id}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
});
```

### ContentScript.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "fromPopup") {
    // Send JSON data back to Popup.
    sendResponse({data: "from Content Script to Popup"});

    // Send JSON data to background page.
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "fromContentScript"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  } else {
    sendResponse({}); // snub them.
  }
});
```

### BackgroundPage.html

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  // From content script.
  if (sender.tab) {
    if (request.method == "fromContentScript")
      sendResponse({data: "Response from Background Page"});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
  }
});
```

Comment: I've run into problems with inline JavaScript in HTML files. Default it seem to be disabled for security reasons, see [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). Simplest solution: move script to .js file and use a script-tag instead. Bonus tips: for page actions you can get the debug console for the popup page using "Inspect Element" in the page.